# php htaccess redirect url contains 'foldername'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect, if the user using the link "http://example.com/site/" to "http://example.com"

I have searched and modified htaccess with many examples, but it doesn't redirects.

I have tried with rewritecond, redirects, but doesn't redirects as desired.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https\:\/\/example\.com\/site\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/site/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Finally i kept my htaccess like below.

### HTACCESS CODE BELOW

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I don't know the possible solutions to overcome such issue.
Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are trying to make rewrite cond without interupting folders you might want to consider using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Answer (score 0):

**Changes Take Time**

When modifying the .htaccess file note that changes may take a while to be observed. The file is not php or html but rather a server configuration file. I have found that on public hosting such as GoDaddy, it has taken up to 20 minutes.

**Redirect an old file to a new file path:**

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Sources:

http://www.htaccess-guide.com

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file